# Python NewType('X', Y): mypy displays error: got Y, expected X

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I want to use a type checker that helps me writing good code and I think [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) does what I want. But I do not get how to write the following code.

```
import typing as tau

Offset = tau.NewType('Offset', tau.Tuple[int, int])


def f(x: int, y: int) -> Offset:
    return x, y


important_for_me = Offset != tau.Tuple[int, int]
assert important_for_me
```

For a framework I am writing it is important to not just assign an identifier to a type, but I still want the typechecker to know how to help me (so not just assign TypeVar and lose information).

typing.NewType works perfectly fine, but mypy gives me an error at line 7:

> Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[int, int]", expected
> "Offset")

Is there a way how to write it exactly like I did but in a way that the typechecker understands it?

[image: error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly create an `Offset` from your `x, y` tuple:

```
def f(x: int, y: int) -> Offset:
    return Offset((x, y))
```

This is because, from [NewType helper function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#newtype-helper-function): "type checkers require explicit casts from `int` where `UserId` is expected", or in your case: from `Tuple[int, int]` to `Offset`.

May just be for your example, but if `f` really does perform no validation on `x` and `y` before returning an `Offset`, a `NewType` here is unnecessary. In that case, I would suggest declaring `Offset` as:

```
Offset = tau.Tuple[int, int]
```

which is a [type alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases).

Comment: Your solution works, thank you :)

A type alias does not support the assertion in the end.